# UTF8 conversion wxString::ToStdString()

Tags: c++, c++11, utf-8, wxwidgets

I am writing application and I am using wxWidgets as GUI backend. Core part of app uses `std::string` and UTF8 as encoding. I need sane way to convert between `wxString` and `std::string`. I know about `wxString::ToUTF8()` but it is somewhat awkward to use (and inefficient I think, as it return some proxy object). There is a better method `wxString::ToStdString()` but, if I understood properly, it uses current locale encoding. Is there a way to configure wxWidgets globally in such a way that it uses UTF8 encoding when converting between `wxString` and narrow char (`const char*`, `std::string`)?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do this, you will have to write your own helper function using `ToUTF8()` or equivalent `utf8_str()`. This will be inefficient in the sense that it will require a conversion from UTF-32 or UTF-16 every time it's called, but this is unlikely to be a bottleneck.